# Can anyone explain why I can still enter copy of this data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to stop two records from being copied into my database but even though I've put in the code it is still happening any help will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
 {
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TOSHIBA0007\\TESTSERVER;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True");
             conn.Open();
             string checkcompany = "select count(*) from Company where CompanyName = @CompanyName";
             SqlCommand cc = new SqlCommand(checkcompany, conn);
             cc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", InputCompany.Text);
             int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cc.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
             conn.Close();

             if (temp == 1)
             {
                 Response.Write("Company is already registered! if this is incorrect please email us at info@getmeanapprentice.com");
             }
         }
}
```

**edit**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

        SqlConnection Comp = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TOSHIBA0007\\TESTSERVER;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("insert into Company(GUID, CompanyName, Password, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, City, PostCode, County, Country, Email, Telephonenumber, Faxnumber)Values(@ID, @CompanyName, @Password, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @AddressLine3, @City, @PostCode, @County, @Country, @Email, @TelephoneNumber, @Faxnumber)",Comp);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", newGUID.ToString());
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", InputCompany.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", InputPassword.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", InputAddress1.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", InputAddress2.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine3", InputAddress3.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", InputCity.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", InputPostcode.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@County", InputCounty.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", InputCountry.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", InputEmail.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelephoneNumber", InputTelephone.Text);
            xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Faxnumber", InputFax.Text);

            Comp.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Comp.Close();

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What code follows this code block?

Comment: Best to put a unique constraint on `CompanyName` and catch the unique key violation to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Check if there isn´t already more than one entry with that company name. You are checking count==1

Comment: If you keep being able to enter multiple copies of the data, I bet `temp` is well over 1 by now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one company with the same name then this line

```
if (temp == 1)
```

will fail, since `temp` will be 2 or more.

Replace this line with

```
if (temp >= 1)
```

Also consider adding a unique constraint on the CompanyName column, since this is critical in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a link between your test and your button click.  You test in page load and write out a warning to the page if there is already a company by this ID.  This won't stop the button click code from running.

You need to do your check for a company in the button click and if exists, don't run that code.

Comment: P.S. posting actual connection strings probably isn't a great idea.

Comment: but its local ? it shouldnt matter should it

Comment: It shouldn't matter, just probably not a great idea.  My company wouldn't be too impressed is for sure.